# CMake: library linking requirements

Tags: linux, cmake

I have a project where I build a library called mylibA that uses calls to the pthread library. In my CMake project file I use the following commands:

```
add_library( mylibA STATIC ${mylib_SRC} )
target_link_library( mylibA pthread )
```

In a separate project, a create an executable that uses mylibA. My CMake project file looks like the following:

```
add_executable( myexe ${myexe_SRC} )
target_link_library( myexe mylibA pthread )
```

If I leave out the pthread link for the executable project, I get encounter link problems. Is it a requirement to link the pthread library against both the library and executable, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build a static library, you don't link it and hence anything you have specified as link dependencies are not included.

However, as of CMake 2.8.12, you can specify an interface (include file, compiler options, etc) that should be used by anyone using the library.

In your case, you can write:

```
add_library(mylibA STATIC ${mylib_SRC})
target_link_libraries(mylibA INTERFACE pthread)
```

Comment: The correct name of the command is actually [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you should link mylibA with pthread. You should wait with linking with pthread till you have an executable.

Why not use something like (copied from another question):

`FIND_PACKAGE ( Threads REQUIRED )
ADD_EXECUTABLE ( test test.cpp )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ( test ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} )`

instead of hard-coding pthread?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you have to remember the different interdependencies of the libraries at the point where creating the executable. Specifying the libraries in the wrong order to `target_link_libraries` will lead to linker errors on some architectures in this case. Doing the `target_link_libraries` already on the static library will allow CMake to chose the correct order automatically when linking the executable.